# How to name method that can only return one entry. (C#, ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, methods, naming-conventions, method-names

I have a method, that returns a List of strings. For some reason I do not allow the method to return a List with more than one string in it. Is it better to name such a method GetEntry or GetEntries?

Comment: It's probably best to make it just return a String.  Is that not an option?

Comment: sorry, forget about the return type, that´s just an example, I am only interested in the naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to make the method return a string rather than a list, but if that is not possible then you should name it so that its name indicates what it does, so `GetEntry` would be better or even `GetSingleEntry` to make it more explicit.

**Edit** As it seems you are not going to necessarily return a list I would just got for `GetEntry`, i would only use `GetSingleEntry` if, for whatever reason, you were returning a list which only had a single entry to make that clear to the callers.  this would not be necessary if the method only returns a string, so in that case `GetEntry` would be sufficient.

Comment: The reason for this is I draw data from a database. Normally, I should only get one row back but I want to collect all data returned. But because receiving more than one row is not "allowed", I want to throw an exception in the method. Do you think this is a good way to handle it?

Comment: if getting more than 1 row is an error then yes it might be appropriate to throw an exception, depending on if there is anything you can do about this.  I think it would be better to return a string and throw if you can't do that because you got an error in you program/data.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it should be getEntry, since it only returns a string; anyway this sounds like more of a personal problem, and not very much of a code problem.

Comment: What the hell do you mean by that?

Comment: No need to curse, all I'm saying is, I don't understand why your asking others what you should name a method. It is more of a personal issue, because what you name your own method is your personal preference.

Comment: Why is it not allowed to ask others about how to name methods? I would like to know their opinion.

Comment: Lol, I'm not trying to get on your case. I just found it a little odd. But whatever, sorry if I offended you or anyone else.

Comment: @James, naming is very important and I think its appropriate to ask questions about that, especially if the methods are going to be used by others.

Comment: Okay, sorry; I guess I just made a newbie mistake. Won't happen again, haha. Still learning.

Answer (score 0):

I would return an IEnumerable, and then use FirstOrDefault() at the call-site.  If you want to return a single item, call it GetSingleStringFromXXX() with the following signature:

```
string GetSingleStringFromXXX(params[] args)
```